# Is it possible to pass an ObjectDataSource to a Web Method through jQuery Ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, objectdatasource

Is it possible to pass an `ObjectDataSource` to a Web method through jquery ajax?

jQuery Ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Webservices/LoadActivities.asmx/LoadMoreData") %>',
    //data: data,
    data: '{"ObjectDataSource1":' + JSON.stringify(jQuery('<%= ObjectDataSource1.ClientID %>')) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

});
```

Object Data Source:

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetActivities" TypeName="MyMethodLocation" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="top" DefaultValue="10" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Web Method: (LoadActivities.asmx)

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class LoadActivities : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void LoadMoreData(ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1) 
    {
        // MANIPULATE OBJECT DATA SOURCE
    }
}
```

If I do the object isn't passed correctly, when the web method is executed it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: What does the JSON look like(the data element) when rendered on the client?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think that manipulating an ObjectDataSource control like that is bad.

If I'm right, you want to remove or raise the top limit for the data source
with no full postback on your page.

In that case, you should use the built-in functionalities of the ObjectDataSource
(for instances, use a ControlParameter to set value of the top limit based on a control value
or set the top limit value on the OnSelecting event)
combined to another way to refresh the data (like surrounding a gridview with an UpdatePanel and calling the DataBind method in the callback).